# Any plug-ins similar to mongrel_proctitle for Phusion passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, load, passenger, mongrel

We migrated our rails app. from Mongrel to Phusion Passenger recently. We had this **mongrel_proctitle**, which used to show the process title in `top`.

This was useful feature for troubleshooting. Are there anyway of getting similar functionality with Phusion Passenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger already automatically sets useful process titles. All your Ruby apps are called "Passenger RackApp: /path-to-your-app". If you need to obtain statistics, just run `passenger-status`.

Comment: Yes, But I don't see the exact call the passenger process is handling. We have only 1 app running so the path to app is the same always and not of much use.

Comment: Thanks Hongli, it's what I needed.